# How to know if initial payment was done with Paypal Recurring Payments? (using Payum)

Tags: symfony, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, payum

I'm setting up the profile a recurring payment.

I want to charge when the user subscribes so in order to make this I use the parameter INITAMT and move the first payment to the next month.

It appears that everything is OK but I can see that I get the same response without considering the buyer outcome.

I have activated the Negative Testing on Paypal and I get the following response (this appears to be the same that the success response).

Can you tell me where can I identify that the INITAMT wasn't done?

Thanks for your help!

```js
{
  "cancelToken": {
    "details": {
      "class": "TheBigSite\\Entity\\RecurringPaymentDetails",
      "id": 13
    },
    "hash": "C5f38V1fzYwfUIJ5JDhz7WAeyMcmmXoHJsvqOloHos8",
    "after_url": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/thebigsite\/recurring\/payment\/payment\/paypal_express_checkout_recurring_payment\/details\/21\/13",
    "target_url": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/thebigsite\/recurring\/payment\/cancel_recurring_payment\/C5f38V1fzYwfUIJ5JDhz7WAeyMcmmXoHJsvqOloHos8",
    "gateway_name": "paypal_express_checkout_recurring_payment"
  },
  "billingAgreementStatus": {
    "model": {
      "details": {
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT": "0.00",
        "L_BILLINGTYPE0": "RecurringPayments",
        "L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0": "Subscription to The Big Site at $ 3.49 USD",
        "NOSHIPPING": 1,
        "AMT": "0.00",
        "INITAMT": 3.49,
        "PROFILESTARTDATE": "2017-01-18T00:01:00Z",
        "RETURNURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/capture\/UGH1kWozEL2aEUKmdOoh7sC8n0KWzB13m9Y7x3GH2lE",
        "CANCELURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/capture\/UGH1kWozEL2aEUKmdOoh7sC8n0KWzB13m9Y7x3GH2lE?cancelled=1",
        "INVNUM": 21,
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION": "Sale",
        "AUTHORIZE_TOKEN_USERACTION": "commit",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/notify\/m45vq7k3vwGGzSbDZTTuUhpGQTtw1ONHo0U7_JwN95A",
        "TOKEN": "EC-7DV447714E7404935",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-18T06:01:55Z",
        "CORRELATIONID": "c9d4dc37acfe",
        "ACK": "Success",
        "VERSION": "65.1",
        "BUILD": "000000",
        "BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS": "1",
        "CHECKOUTSTATUS": "PaymentActionNotInitiated",
        "CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "HANDLINGAMT": "0.00",
        "TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "NOTIFYURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/notify\/m45vq7k3vwGGzSbDZTTuUhpGQTtw1ONHo0U7_JwN95A",
        "INSURANCEAMT": "0.00",
        "SHIPDISCAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED": "false",
        "PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE": "0",
        "EMAIL": "buyer@theemail.com",
        "PAYERID": "YKBEZG2VKU2RY",
        "PAYERSTATUS": "verified",
        "FIRSTNAME": "Pedro",
        "LASTNAME": "Fernandez",
        "COUNTRYCODE": "US"
      },
      "id": 21
    },
    "first_model": {
      "details": {
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT": "0.00",
        "L_BILLINGTYPE0": "RecurringPayments",
        "L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0": "Subscription to The Big Site at $ 3.49 USD",
        "NOSHIPPING": 1,
        "AMT": "0.00",
        "INITAMT": 3.49,
        "PROFILESTARTDATE": "2017-01-18T00:01:00Z",
        "RETURNURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/capture\/UGH1kWozEL2aEUKmdOoh7sC8n0KWzB13m9Y7x3GH2lE",
        "CANCELURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/capture\/UGH1kWozEL2aEUKmdOoh7sC8n0KWzB13m9Y7x3GH2lE?cancelled=1",
        "INVNUM": 21,
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION": "Sale",
        "AUTHORIZE_TOKEN_USERACTION": "commit",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/notify\/m45vq7k3vwGGzSbDZTTuUhpGQTtw1ONHo0U7_JwN95A",
        "TOKEN": "EC-7DV447714E7404935",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-18T06:01:55Z",
        "CORRELATIONID": "c9d4dc37acfe",
        "ACK": "Success",
        "VERSION": "65.1",
        "BUILD": "000000",
        "BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS": "1",
        "CHECKOUTSTATUS": "PaymentActionNotInitiated",
        "CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "HANDLINGAMT": "0.00",
        "TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "NOTIFYURL": "http:\/\/api.thebigsite.dev\/app_dev.php\/payment\/notify\/m45vq7k3vwGGzSbDZTTuUhpGQTtw1ONHo0U7_JwN95A",
        "INSURANCEAMT": "0.00",
        "SHIPDISCAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT": "0.00",
        "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED": "false",
        "PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE": "0",
        "EMAIL": "thebuyer@email.com",
        "PAYERID": "YKBEZG2VKU2RY",
        "PAYERSTATUS": "verified",
        "FIRSTNAME": "Pedro",
        "LASTNAME": "Fernandez",
        "COUNTRYCODE": "US"
      },
      "id": 21
    },
    "status": "captured"
  },
  "recurringPaymentStatus": {
    "model": {
      "details": {
        "TOKEN": "EC-7DV447714E7404935",
        "DESC": "Subscription to The Big Site at $ 3.49 USD",
        "EMAIL": "thebuyer@email.com",
        "AMT": "3.49",
        "CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "BILLINGFREQUENCY": "12",
        "PROFILESTARTDATE": "2017-01-18T08:00:00Z",
        "BILLINGPERIOD": "Month",
        "FAILEDINITAMTACTION": "CancelOnFailure",
        "PROFILEID": "I-75R2MWY6FW5M",
        "PROFILESTATUS": "ActiveProfile",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-18T06:01:57Z",
        "CORRELATIONID": "dc6b877e7266a",
        "ACK": "Success",
        "VERSION": "65.1",
        "BUILD": "24616352",
        "STATUS": "Active",
        "AUTOBILLOUTAMT": "NoAutoBill",
        "MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS": "0",
        "SUBSCRIBERNAME": "Pedro Fernandez",
        "NEXTBILLINGDATE": "2017-01-18T10:00:00Z",
        "NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED": "0",
        "NUMCYCLESREMAINING": "0",
        "OUTSTANDINGBALANCE": "0.00",
        "FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT": "0",
        "TRIALAMTPAID": "0.00",
        "REGULARAMTPAID": "0.00",
        "AGGREGATEAMT": "0.00",
        "AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT": "0.00",
        "FINALPAYMENTDUEDATE": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "TOTALBILLINGCYCLES": "0",
        "SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "REGULARBILLINGPERIOD": "Month",
        "REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY": "12",
        "REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES": "0",
        "REGULARCURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "REGULARAMT": "3.49",
        "REGULARSHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "REGULARTAXAMT": "0.00"
      },
      "id": 13
    },
    "first_model": {
      "details": {
        "TOKEN": "EC-7DV447714E7404935",
        "DESC": "Subscription to The Big Site at $ 3.49 USD",
        "EMAIL": "thebuyer@email.com",
        "AMT": "3.49",
        "CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "BILLINGFREQUENCY": "12",
        "PROFILESTARTDATE": "2017-01-18T08:00:00Z",
        "BILLINGPERIOD": "Month",
        "FAILEDINITAMTACTION": "CancelOnFailure",
        "PROFILEID": "I-75R2MWY6FW5M",
        "PROFILESTATUS": "ActiveProfile",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-18T06:01:57Z",
        "CORRELATIONID": "dc6b877e7266a",
        "ACK": "Success",
        "VERSION": "65.1",
        "BUILD": "24616352",
        "STATUS": "Active",
        "AUTOBILLOUTAMT": "NoAutoBill",
        "MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS": "0",
        "SUBSCRIBERNAME": "Pedro Fernandez",
        "NEXTBILLINGDATE": "2017-01-18T10:00:00Z",
        "NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED": "0",
        "NUMCYCLESREMAINING": "0",
        "OUTSTANDINGBALANCE": "0.00",
        "FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT": "0",
        "TRIALAMTPAID": "0.00",
        "REGULARAMTPAID": "0.00",
        "AGGREGATEAMT": "0.00",
        "AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT": "0.00",
        "FINALPAYMENTDUEDATE": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "TOTALBILLINGCYCLES": "0",
        "SHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "TAXAMT": "0.00",
        "REGULARBILLINGPERIOD": "Month",
        "REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY": "12",
        "REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES": "0",
        "REGULARCURRENCYCODE": "USD",
        "REGULARAMT": "3.49",
        "REGULARSHIPPINGAMT": "0.00",
        "REGULARTAXAMT": "0.00"
      },
      "id": 13
    },
    "status": "captured"
  },
  "gatewayName": "paypal_express_checkout_recurring_payment"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [paypal verifying first payment or initamt was billed in recurring payment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568003/paypal-verifying-first-payment-or-initamt-was-billed-in-recurring-payment)

Comment: You can rely on BILLINGPERIOD set in payment details to tell if it is recurring or not. https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Action/RecurringPaymentDetailsStatusAction.php#L96